Inheretence in Python With Different Args
I am a C++ programmer at heart, but have (unfortunately) been forced to use python for the time being. I've been trying to get inheritance in python working, and have had no success so far. I've tried every combination of **kwargs and *args I can find online, and nothing seems to work. (What I suspect is) the closest I've come is the below, but still no success. Does anyone have any ideas?
import torch

class Foo(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, channels, l_filter, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Foo", Foo.__mro__)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class Bar(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, aggr, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Bar", Bar.__mro__)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class FooBar(Bar, Foo):
    def __init__(self, channels : int, l_filter: int, *args, **kwargs):
        print("FooBar", FooBar.__mro__)
        super(Bar, self).__init__(aggr = 'add', *args, **kwargs)
        super(Foo, self).__init__(channels = channels, l_filter = l_filter, *args, **kwargs)

class FooBarBaz(FooBar):
    def __init__(self, channels : int, l_filter: int, *args, **kwargs):
        print("FooBarBaz", FooBarBaz.__mro__)
        super().__init__(channels = channels, l_filter = l_filter, *args, **kwargs)

    def doThings():
        print("Done!")

foo_bar_baz = FooBarBaz(channels = 3, l_filter = 7)
foo_bar_baz.doThings()

The error I get is:
FooBarBaz (<class '__main__.FooBarBaz'>, <class '__main__.FooBar'>, <class '__main__.Bar'>, <class '__main__.Foo'>, <class 'torch.nn.modules.module.Module'>, <class 'object'>)
FooBar (<class '__main__.FooBar'>, <class '__main__.Bar'>, <class '__main__.Foo'>, <class 'torch.nn.modules.module.Module'>, <class 'object'>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<path>/multi.py", line 27, in <module>
    foo_bar_baz = FooBarBaz(channels = 3, l_filter = 7)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<path>/multi.py", line 22, in __init__
    super().__init__(channels = channels, l_filter = l_filter, **kwargs)
  File "<path>/multi.py", line 16, in __init__
    super(Bar, self).__init__(aggr = 'add', **kwargs)
TypeError: Foo.__init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'channels' and 'l_filter'

I've spent all day fighting with it, with no progress:

If I remove the torch.nn.Module from the hirearchy, I don't see any change.
If I remove *args everywhere I get no change.
If I manually modify **kwargs in FooBar.__init__() to add values for aggr prior to the call to super(Bar, self).__init__(...), nothing changes`
Swapping the order of super() calls in the FooBar ctor (I know this shouldn't work given the MRO, but I had to try it...) just gives a comparable error.

What am I doing wrong? I know it can't be as hard as I am making it, especially when the MRO is exactly what I would imagining
Does anyone have any thoughts? I am pulling my hair out at this point
